# Tycho/Maven cross references between source directories of the same plugin

Tags: java, maven, reference, tycho

when building a project using Maven and Tycho, I receive an error message saying Class xy "cannot be resolved to a type". This happens on multiple occasions with one thing they all have in common:

In the plugins, there are 1-3 source directories (e.g. src, src-gen and xtend-gen). If there is a class in one of the source directories (e.g. src-gen) referencing/using a class from any other directory (e.g. src) but from the same plugin, the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to specify jars.compile.order in build.properties, see

http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/BuildProperties.html

otherwise tycho cannot know in which dependency order the source directories should be compiled.